# How to install Perl module Crypt::OpenSSL::AES?

Tags: linux, openssl

It's been a couple of days I am pulling my hair trying to get a legacy Perl script working as cgi within an apache2 server. It requires Crypt::OpenSSL::AES. From the Apache error logs:

```
Can't locate Crypt/OpenSSL/AES.pm in @INC
```

The easiest would have been if a ubuntu package could install it with me, but I am unable to locate any package with the proper files. The following returns nothing:

```
apt-file search AES.pm
```

As a regular user, I have installed cpan and used it to install perl modules, so that Crypt::OpenSSL::AES *is* installed under my user directory at `/home/user/.cpan/build/Crypt-OpenSSL-AES-0.02-H74J64/lib`.  Unfortunately, whether I manually copy AES.pm to its proper location (`/usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1/...` as per @INC) or I add the PERL5LIB env variable within the apache2 configuration files (`SetEnv PERL5LIB /home/user/.cpan/build/Crypt-OpenSSL-AES-0.02-H74J64/lib`), the error logs now show that there is a missing shared object:

```
Can't locate loadable object for module Crypt::OpenSSL::AES in @INC
```

The error mesage is subtly different from the first one (I didn't notice it at first): now it *does* find AES.pm, but there is another dependency on an unspecified "loadable object" and I have no clue which one. Openssl is installed on my system.

So:

Generally, what is the proper way (on a Linux-ubuntu system) to install perl modules to work with an apache2 server? (I searched and there are many answers to this question, but it still doesn't work).

Specifically, how can I properly satisfy my cgi perl application's dependency on Crypt::OpenSSL::AES?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved my problem:

1. Installing the package

   **Debian and Ubuntu**

   ```
   aptitude install libssl-dev
   ```

   **CentOS or Fedora**

   ```
   yum install -y openssl-devel`
   ```
2. Compiling the module manually

   ```
   sudo cpan Crypt/OpenSSL/AES.pm
   ```

Comment: on CentOS, just `yum -y install perl-Crypt-OpenSSL-RSA`

Answer (score 1):

Usually there are *-dev packages in the Ubuntu repository, for developers and administrators to build other software. So the packages to merely run the program can get smaller in size.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at http://debian.pkgs.cpan.org/. It provides a way for you to generate your own .deb files from CPAN packages. You could try to just shotgun their pre-packaged ones, but just be very aware that they could break due to differences between the Debian machines they were built for and whatever version of Ubuntu you are using: *"There be Dragon's Here."*

Comment: Thank you. That looks very interesting. I already have a working system so I am not going to break it now, but I bookmarked your page and will try it next time I have a similar need.

Comment: Link is broken :-(.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating package with `dh-make-perl` (https://wiki.debian.org/PerlFAQ)? A bit too late, but it might help to someone.